Raid 1 and LUKS encryption on ubuntu server 24.04
I am trying to install Ubuntu server 24.04, and was hoping to use both raid 1 (two NVME disks) and LUKS encryption for the OS. The hope is to have the server continue working if one disk fails. I tried doing hardware raid 1 on my motherboard and installing 24.04, but even though the raid is active in BIOS, it still shows me two disks to install the OS on, so I thought I might be able to use the installer to create an encrypted raid 1 volume. Unfortunately I'm running into problems: after selecting a custom layout and creating a software raid with the two disks, I cannot select them to create an encrypted volume group. In fact, upon selecting "create volume group" all the device names are blacked out, although I can manually click select the empty spaces to infer which device is which by looking at total group space. I see my SATA drives, but the 512Gb NVMEs are gone from the selection and the raid md0 group does not appear there at all.
Question: is there a way to create a LUKS encrypted raid 1 group for the OS drive on Ubuntu 24.04 server? Thank you.
